# SSRS conditional expression help to count distinct by group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I've got a report where I want to return the distinct count of [Above MRL]

e.g. Canola counts 13 being the sum of the number of times all the Sample IDs are [Above MRL].

Sample ID 330174 has a value of two, because this sample has been above MRL twice. I only want to count Sample ID 330174 once. Then roll this number up to the Canola level. Then I want to roll these products like almond, apples, canola to the plant level. So everything needs to be counted only once and summed.

How do I achieve this with an expression?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to count the number of Sample IDs if the Sample Above MR is equal to 1.

```
=CountDistinct(IIF(Fields!AboveMRL.Value = 1, Fields!SampleID.Value, NOTHING))
```

This will check if the Sample if AboveMRL and, if so, count the ID. NOTHING is like NULL and is not counted in a Count Distinct calculation. If there are two of the same sample ID, it will only be counted once.